# How to fetch attribute value of parent node from child nodelist.(XPath)

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, attributes, parent-node

Here's the requirement

I have a xml document which looks something like this

```
-<page height="777" width="777">
    -<block r="777" l="777" blockType="Separator">
        +<region>
        +<separator>
    -<block r="777" l="777" blockType="Separator">
        +<region>
        +<separator>
    -<block r="777" l="777" blockType="Text">
        +<region>
        +<text>
</page>
```

I have all the separator blocks in ***separatorNodeList***

```
    String expression = "//page/block/separator";
    XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile(expression);
    NodeList separatorNodeList = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Now, i am trying to get the **attribute(r,l) value** of **parent node** of separator block.i.e. something like

```
int separatorDistanceFromRight = Integer.parseInt(((Element)separatorNodeList.item(i)).getParentNode().getAttribute("r"));
```

But the above doesn't seem to work. Any Quick help ??

Comment: Try to separate your expression into variables, and see which part return unexpected value; put `(Element)separatorNodeList.item(i)` in a variable, `.getParentNode()` in a variable, so on.

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't seem to work". Is there a compilation error? runtime error? Does it return the wrong value? If so, what value does it return? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/auto-detect-the-phrase-it-doesnt-work-and-ask-user-if-enough-info-given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh,i found this.

```
int separatorDistanceFromRight = Integer.parseInt(separatorNodeList.item(i).getParentNode().getAttributes().getNamedItem("r").getNodeValue());
```